# Is there an easy way to get the data from an sql databank and put it in an listbox in C#?

Tags: c#, sql

Is there an easy way to get the data from an sql databank and put it in an list/listbox in C#
so i can sort it afterwards and search for it.

Comment: use ado.net, or some orm. note we often call database, not databank.

Comment: ok thanks sry im kinda new here and still in school so yea